# Java Generics type conversion puzzle

Tags: java, generics, guava

I'm attempting to use Google's Guava ImmutableSet class to create a set of immutable classes with timelike properties (java.util.Date, and org.joda.time.DateTime).

```
private static final ImmutableSet<Class<?>> timeLikeObjects = ImmutableSet.of(Date.class, DateTime.class);
```

I'm completely stumped as to why I'm getting this compiler error (Java 1.6 in eclipse).

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImmutableSet<Class<? extends Object&Serializable&Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>>>> to ImmutableSet<Class<?>>
```

Note that this works:

```
private static final ImmutableSet<?> timeLikeObjects = ImmutableSet.of(Date.class, DateTime.class);
```

However I obviously loose part of the generic description of the timeLikeObjects type.

I've never run across the ampersand symbol in a generic description, and it doesn't appear to be valid syntax.

Is there a way to specify multiple inheritance in Java Generics that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically the compiler is trying to be smart for you. It's working out some bounds for you, and trying to use them for the return type of `of`.

Fortunately, you can fix it by being explicit:

```
private static final ImmutableSet<Class<?>> timeLikeObjects =
    ImmutableSet.<Class<?>>of(Date.class, DateTime.class);
```

The `&` part *is* valid syntax - it's how you specify bounds for multiple types, e.g.

```
public class Foo<T extends Serializable & Comparable<T>>
```

That means you can only specify types for `T` which implement `Serializable` *and* `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: Jon this was an extremely enlightening response.  You're solution works perfectly.  Thanks! :)